# Adobe Flash AS3: Getting the data of selected item in a list that has a MouseEvent

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

i have a list of songs and if I double click an Item, it will play the song. I do it like this. aList is the instance name of the list.

```
aList.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, changeSong);

function changeSong(e:MouseEvent) {
     ....
     song = e.target.selectedItem.data;
     ....
}
```

I have the error in the part of (song = e.target.selectedItem.data;) . It seems like i used a wrong property.

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property selectedItem not found on    fl.controls.listClasses.CellRenderer and there is no default value.
at playlist_fla::MainTimeline/changeSong()
```

Do anyone know how to properly get the item's data. Because I think my syntax is wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to me that the event target isn't the `List`, but rather a `CellItemRenderer`. A better way would be to do something like this:
`var list:List = e.target as List;` `song = list.selectedItem` and see if the cast succeeds.

Comment: @TomislavDyulgerov it says 1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type String. and it is pointing in the song = list.selecteditem; . Could you tell me What could be the cause of this error?

Comment: Oh, you have to cast again. In case your song is of type `String` your code should look like this: `song = list.selectedItem as String;`

Comment: @TomislavDyulgerov when i trace the list variable, it is null. and when i trace the e.target is prints [object Cellrenderer] . What could this possibly mean?

Answer (score 0):

What have you assigned as the List component's dataProvider?

`e.target.data` is an object with additional properties.

If you're unsure of the properties of the data object, you can iterate thru one like this:

```
for (var property:String in data)
{
    trace("data." + property + " = " + data[property]);
}
```

If it's the label of a standard itemRenderer that you are trying to assign to the song variable you're likely to succeed with:

`song = e.target.listData.label;`